# Is it bad or good practice to use $interval/$timeout to pull data from the API?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote an API server in node.js and the frontend is written in angularJS.
I'm using firebase on the backend side (I heard that using firebase on the frontend side is not safe).

So I can't use firebase to pull the data in angularJS and in order to pull the data to show in the UI that the data changed, I just wrote this code:

```
$interval(
  function() 
  {
    _getUserContracts(); 
  }, 50000
);
```

Is this OK?

Comment: "i heard that to use firebase in frotnend side is not safety" probably isn't true. Where did you hear that?

Comment: It certainly is bad practice :(

Comment: @ceejayoz yes .. never use firebase or consume critical data api's via frontend .

Comment: @atulquest93 That doesn't appear to be true. Firebase is explicitly built for front-end work, and is widely used in production. It's entirely possible to do securely if you do it right. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data

Answer (score 4):

Please do not use timeouts. You cannot be sure that server will definitely return a result in the given period. Use promises instead. AngularJS has a $q service just for this.

Comment: Can't upvote enough. Recently ran into a nasty issue on one of our apps b/c someone was using timeouts instead of promises.

Comment: So anyone can give me  a example for good practice?

Comment: This is a great one: http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Comment: @sohel101091This example dose not check for data changes,

Comment: Well,how about Firebase Cloud Messaging (

Comment: @sohel101091 can you tell me  please what's about "promises"? i Don't understand,i use interval timeout in order to revoke the function over and over again,promise will do that  for me as well,but only one time calling,and no over and over